# Who is the deity of middle direction?

Tags: identification-request, brahma, deity

Most of us know that Astha Dikpalakas are the deities of eight directions. But, Who is the deity of middle direction?

Also, I saw Brahma in middle among them in some pictures of Vastu. But, Is Brahma actually a deity of middle?

Comment: middle can't be a direction. It is just a point. You can have different directions from that point. In Vastu, the middle point is known as Brahmasthana. It should be kept open. No heavy load should be placed here. But it is not a direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 10 directions. 8 you should already know, but there's two more, Ananta and Brahmaa. Brahmaa goes down, Ananta goes up.

> दशमांशाः स्वतश्चौजे युग्मे तन्नवमात् स्मृताः ।
> दश पूर्वादिदिक्पाला इन्द्राऽग्नियमराक्षसाः ॥ १३॥
> For the Dashamsha Chakra, starting from it's own location, for odd Raashis, and from the 9th for even Raashis, there are 10 Dikpaalas (protector/ruler/sustainers of the directions), beginning from east. They are: Indra, Agni, Yama, Raakshasha

> वरुणो मारुतश्चैव कुबेरेशानपद्मजाः ।
> अनन्तश्च क्रमादोजे समे वा व्युत्क्रमेण तु ॥ १४॥
> Varuna, Maaruta, Kubera, Ishaana, Padmaja(Born from Lotus aka Brahmaa) and Ananta, step by step for odd raashis, and in reverse order for even.

[Source: Brihat Paaraashara Hora Shashtra, षोदशवर्गाध्यायः 13-14](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_sociology_astrology/par0110.html)

Comment: Is Ananta Adi Sesha or anyone else?

Comment: @Boovanaes It most likely refers to Ananta Shesha. Keep in mind that Brahmaa is named as Padmaja, we know that that lotus refers to the one that arises from Vishnu's navel. So, reasonably, we can assume that Ananta also has some relation to Vishnu. I'm inclined to believe that Ananta is Ananta Shesha, but, I'm not aware of any source or proof of this.